# Projected polar chessboard measure convergence in total variation?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, pr.probability, probability-distributions

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\C{\mathbb C}\newcommand\ga{\gamma}$For natural $n$, let $E_n$ be the set of all points in $\R^2$ with "polar coordinates" $(r,t)$ in the set
$$F_n:=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\bigcup_{j=1}^n F_{n;i,j}\subset(0,\infty)\times(0,2\pi]\subset\R^2,$$
where
\begin{equation*}
     F_{n;i,j}:=\Big(\frac{i-1}n,\frac in\Big]\times(t^*_{n;i,j},t^{**}_{n;i,j}], 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    t^*_{n;i,j}:=\frac\pi n\Big(2j-2+\frac{1+(-1)^i}2\Big), \quad 
    t^{**}_{n;i,j}:=\frac\pi n\Big(2j-1+\frac{1+(-1)^i}2\Big). 
\end{equation*}
Slightly more precisely,
\begin{equation*}
    E_n:=\{(r\cos t,r\sin t)\colon(r,t)\in F_n\}. \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}

Here is the intersection (colored light blue) of the set $E_{20}$ with the unit disk:

[image]

So, we have a kind of chessboard in polar coordinates over the entire plane.

Let $\ga^{\otimes2}$ denote the standard normal distribution over $\R^2$. Let
$$\nu_n(B):=\ga^{\otimes2}(E_n\cap B)$$
for all Borel subsets $B$ of $\R^2$.
For any unit vector $u\in\R^2$, let $\nu_{n,u}$ be the pushforward of the measure $\nu_n$ under the projection map $\R^2\ni x\mapsto p_u(x):=u\cdot x\in\R$, where $\cdot$ denotes the dot product.

> Is it then true that $\nu_{n,u}$ converges (as $n\to\infty$) in total variation to $\frac12\,\ga$, where $\ga$ is the standard normal distribution over $\R$?

---

**Discussion:**

The intuition behind this conjecture is as follows:

- recall that $\nu_{n,u}$ is the pushforward of the measure $\nu_n$ under the  map $p_u$;
- note that $\ga$ is the pushforward of the measure $\ga^{\otimes2}$ under the  map $p_u$;
- note that the total $\nu_n$-mass of $\R^2$ is $\frac12$ of the total $\ga^{\otimes2}$-mass of $\R^2$ and this fraction, $\frac12$, seems to stay almost uniform over $\R^2$ for large $n$;
- so, it seems plausible that $\nu_{n,u}$ will be close to $\frac12$ of $\ga$ -- even in the total variation sense, because the projection $p_u$ should smooth out the density of the measure $\nu_n$.

Note that, to prove that $\nu_{n,u}$ converges in total variation to $\frac12\,\ga$, it is enough (in view of dominated convergence) to show that the density of $\nu_{n,u}$ (w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure over $\R$) converges to the density  of $\frac12\,\ga$ almost everywhere. That is, (in view of the rotational symmetry of the measure $\ga^{\otimes2}$) it is enough to show that for each  unit vector $u\in\R^2$ and almost all $s\in\R$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \int_\R dt\,g(t)\,1(sv+tu\in E_n)\to\frac12, \tag{10}\label{10} 
\end{equation*}
where $g$ is the standard normal density and $v$ is either one of the two unit vectors in $\R^2$ orthogonal to $u$. So, the conjectured effect of the indicator $t\mapsto1(sv+tu\in E_n)$ in \eqref{10} is to approximately halve the total standard normal probability mass of $\R$, for almost all $s\in\R$.

The latter indicator is rather complicated, since the set $E_n$ is rather complicated. So, it makes sense to spell out this indicator.
First here is the trivial remark that, by symmetry, without loss of generality $s>0$ in \eqref{10}.
Next, the equation of any straight line in $\R^2$ in polar coordinates $r,t$ is of the form $r\cos(t-t_0)=s$ for some real $s>0$ and some real $t_0$.
So, in view of \eqref{0}, we can rewrite \eqref{10} as
\begin{equation*}
    H_{t_0,n}(s):=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^n \ga(T_{n;i,j}(t_0,s))\to\frac12 \tag{10a}\label{10a}
\end{equation*}
for each $t_0\in[0,\pi)$ and almost all real $s>0$,
where
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    T_{n;i,j}(t_0,s)&:=\Big\{s \tan(t-t_0)\colon t\in(t^*_{n;i,j},t^{**}_{n;i,j}],\ 
    \cos(t-t_0)\in\Big[\frac{ns}{i},\frac{ns}{i-1}\Big)\Big\} \\ 
&   =\Big\{s \tan u\colon u\in(t^*_{n;i,j}-t_0,t^{**}_{n;i,j}-t_0],\ 
    \cos u\in\Big[\frac{ns}{i},\frac{ns}{i-1}\Big)\Big\},   
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
with $\frac{ns}{i-1}:=\infty$ for $i=1$. (Of course, here we can express $\tan u$ in terms of $\cos u$, depending on which of the four quarters of the interval $[0,2\pi)$ the value of $u\mod2\pi$ is in. Also, because $\cos\le1$, we can replace $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$ in \eqref{10a} by $\sum_{i=\lfloor ns\rfloor+1}^\infty$. Even for $i\ge\lfloor ns\rfloor+1$, the sets $T_{n;i,j}(t_0,s)$ will be empty for most of the $j$'s.)

---

**Update:** Below are the graphs $\{(s,H_{1,n}(s)-\frac12)\colon0<s<4\}$ for $n=5$ (black), $n=10$ (blue), and $n=20$ (green). If I was not mistaken, we seem to have some improvement going from $n=5$ to $n=10$, but (to my surprise) no improvement going from $n=10$ to $n=20$.

Perhaps, $n=20$ is still a small number in this context, even though the calculations for $n=20$ are already rather heavy.

Or perhaps the conjecture is false. Perhaps this "chessboard" is too "regular" and has to be modified somehow to get the desired effect.

[image]

Comment: What tools/software did you use to make that graphic?

Comment: Do you know the limit of $E_{n}$ by the way? Is it some fractal set? I am guessing it has fat-Cantor-measure to get the 1/2?

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal : Thank you for your interest. I used Mathematica. Each blue cell of this round middle piece of the "chessboard" is a separate parametric plot.

Comment: @ThomasKojar : Thank you for your interest. I am not sure in what sense to take a limit of $E_n$. Perhaps, one can get a fractal as a limit of $E_{2^k}$ as $k\to\infty$.